# Anyone tried tabletop_object_detector for Kinect based pointclouds

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Does the tabletop_object_detector work for the point clouds given by the Kinect? Has anyone tried and succeeded in detecting objects. I have this doubt as its not mentioned in the wiki.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12568/anyone-tried-tabletop_object_detector-for-kinect-based-pointclouds/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-17**:
@Karthik
Have you succeeded in detecting objects using tabletop_object_detector for point clouds given by kinect !
as I'm working on it now ..

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-02**:
@karthik @RiskTeam Have you succeeded in detecting objects using tabletop_object_detector for point clouds given by kinect, and also how did you download the package?' thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it works just fine with Kinect pointclouds.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2012-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-17**:
@arebgun
How can I do this ??

**Comment by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) on 2013-03-17**:
Any point cloud will do.  Just remap cloud_in to be your kinect point cloud.  (Which you can generate by launching openni.launch in package openni_launch.)

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-02**:
@hsiao how did you download the package??